# Get error when accessing RadioButtonList from javascript that exist in a page that have master page

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a asp.net page that has a master page and it contain RadioButtonList1 and I try to do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


            var radioButtonList = document.getElementById('<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID%>');
            if(radioButtonList[0].checked)
                document.getElementById("_secondTR").style.display = "block";
            else if (radioButtonList[1].checked )
                document.getElementById("_secondTR").style.display = "none";
        }  
</script>

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr id="Tr1">
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"  BackColor="#FFCC99"
                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="117px" onclick="ShowHide()">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="_secondTR" runat="server" style="display: none">
        <td>
            <asp:RadioButton ID="Five" runat="server" GroupName="1" BackColor="#669999" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="Four" runat="server" GroupName="1" CausesValidation="True" BackColor="#669999" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can't get RadioButtonList1 from JavaScript.

Comment: Not being conversant with .net, could you post the actual javascript code seen by the browser/interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

THE FOLLOWING IS THE actual javascript code seen by the browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
    Untitled Page
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTY3MTM1NjkwNw9kFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBDxYCHgVzdHlsZQUNZGlzcGxheTpub25lO2QYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgQFLmN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkV2ViVXNlckNvbnRyb2wxJEZpdmUFLmN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkV2ViVXNlckNvbnRyb2wxJEZpdmUFLmN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkV2ViVXNlckNvbnRyb2wxJEZvdXIFLmN0bDAwJENvbnRlbnRQbGFjZUhvbGRlcjEkV2ViVXNlckNvbnRyb2wxJEZvdXLEUVfizbUknWTXdgpHXciIE+acfQ==" />
</div>

<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBgLV9tHzCQLJ7qOsBgLW7qOsBgLGgYnCCgKixI2BBALP88ewCU+8LBEmqBjXFfT7h0XYnYX89px3" />
</div>
    <div>
        asda sd sd as das



<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHide()
        {
  var radioButtonList = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_RadioButtonList1');

            if(radioButtonList[0].checked)
                document.getElementById("_secondTR").style.display = "block";
            else if (radioButtonList[1].checked )
                document.getElementById("_secondTR").style.display = "none";
        }  
</script>

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr id="Tr1">
        <td>
            <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_RadioButtonList1" onclick="ShowHide()" border="0" style="background-color:#FFCC99;width:117px;">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$WebUserControl1$RadioButtonList1" value="1" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_RadioButtonList1_0">Yes</label></td><td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$WebUserControl1$RadioButtonList1" value="0" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_RadioButtonList1_1">No</label></td>
    </tr>
</table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1__secondTR" style="display:none;">
    <td>
            <span style="background-color:#669999;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_Five" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$WebUserControl1$1" value="Five" /></span>
            <span style="background-color:#669999;"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_Four" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$WebUserControl1$1" value="Four" /></span>
        </td>
</tr>

</table>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

.net is generating a table for your list of buttons, radioButtonList referseto that table,
to get the buttons you need to add the following :

```
 radioButtonList = radioButtonList.getElementsByTagName ('input');
```

That solves your immediate problem, but getElementById ('_secondTR') throws an error.

Changing the javascript to the following appears to do what you want.

```
function ShowHide () {
  var radioButtonList = document.getElementById ('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1_RadioButtonList1');
  radioButtonList = radioButtonList.getElementsByTagName ('input');
  if (radioButtonList[0].checked)
    document.getElementById ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1__secondTR").style.display = "block";
  else if (radioButtonList[1].checked )
    document.getElementById ("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WebUserControl1__secondTR").style.display = "none";
}
```

I will have to defer to a .net expert to tell you how to cleanly generate this script.

Comment: it will work but you use statuc id for controls in which if master page changed it will get error